# PHP : How to break a line

Tags: php, wordpress

I am programming on wordpress and I want to edit a php file. I want the text to be displayed with line breaks and not all in one line.

Here is my code(I want jonh in one line and travolta in another but it gets displayed in one):

```
    <div class="slide">
     <img class="animated fade_left" src='<?php echo esc_url(onepage_get_option('onepage_testimonial_2_image', ONEPAGE_DIR_URI . "assets/images/team2.jpg")); ?>' onmouseover="javascript: this.title = '';" title="">
                        <div class="bx-caption animated fade_right"><span><a class="arrow"></a><?php echo esc_attr(onepage_get_option('onepage_testimonial_2_content', __('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.','one-page'))); ?><a class="testimonial"><?php echo esc_attr(onepage_get_option('onepage_testimonial_2_name', __('john \n travolta','one-page'))); ?></a></span></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'john \n travolta','one-page' already done :) still not working

Comment: or you can add echo " <br /> ";

Comment: add " " instead  of '' i.e: "john \n travolta"

Comment: Unless the output is in `<pre>` then a simple line break in the code won't do it, as @mariusz pointed out, just include a `<br />` tag where you want the line break to be. Or output in a defined width container and let the browser wrap the text naturally.

Comment: I tried it but it displays on my website :  john <br/> travolta

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link / element with the class `testimonial` on a new line, I would use css as that keeps it flexible and makes it easy to change if you want to do it differently in the future.

So in your css file:

```
.testimonial {
    display: block;
}
```

In general, I would try to keep presentational stuff out of the php code.

Comment: I agree with you but doesn't work this way..any suggestion for css breakline?

Comment: @grlouk You could add a `span` around the last name: `John <span class="last-name">Travolta</span>` and put the css on that element.

Comment: put css on that element? can you please explain?